# NestJS tests failing: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-testing

I'm seeing a weird error in my test file for a NestJS application. I can't seem to figure out, what went wrong: I have a test file for a TypeORM repository:

```
describe('UserRepository', () => {
    let userRepository;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
          providers: [
            UserRepository,
          ],
        }).compile();
    
        userRepository = await module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
      });

    describe('signUp', () => {
        let save;

        beforeEach(() => {
            save = jest.fn();
            userRepository.create = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ save });
        });

        it('successfully signs up the user', async () => {
            save.mockResolvedValue(undefined);
            expect(
                userRepository.createUser(mockCredentialsDto),
            ).resolves.not.toThrow();
        });
    });
});
```

And a repository:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {

    async createUser(signUpDto: SignUpDto) {
        const { password, email } = signUpDto;

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const encodedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const user: any = this.create();
        user.email = email;
        user.password = encodedPassword;
        user.salt = salt;
        await user.save();

        return user;
    }
}
```

However, the `this.create()` method doesn't seem to work. It seems to return `undefined` and ultimately I get an error for my tests (even though the tests are all passing:

> Received promise rejected instead of resolved Rejected to value:
> [TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined]

Can anyone help? I can't seem to figure out, why `user` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing was the return statement for the test (!):

Here's an excerpt from the Jest documentation:

"Be sure to return the assertion—if you omit this return statement, your test will complete before the promise returned from fetchData is resolved and then() has a chance to execute the callback."

Here is the correct test:

```
it('throws a conflict exception as username already exists', () => {
   save.mockRejectedValue({ code: '23505' });
   return expect(
       userRepository
            .createUser(mockCredentialsDto),
       ).rejects.toThrow(ConflictException);
});
```